# Build virtual Raster Error

Tags: virtual-raster

enter image description here[image: Log]

I am following step by step the online tutorial on QGIS website to learn how to build a virtual raster using the images provided with the tutorial. I am on a Mac with QGIS 3.8, yet when running the algorithm 'Build Virtual Raster' I receive the following error "The following layers were not correctly generated" (see picture) and no layer is created...
Any clue?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Can you show the settings you use when creating the virtual layer?

Answer (score 2):

Try saving to a location where the output path does not contain a period, i.e. the directory with this name: 'QGIS-Training-Data-2.0' The period may be interpreted as the beginning of the file extension which would cause the path to point to a non existent directory. Macs are usually tolerant of unusual characters in a file path but QGIS on a Mac has proven (to me at least) not to be so lenient.

Comment: If I had enough reputation points I would have commented. I can comment on this because it's a comment on my 'answer'. Also, it's interesting that the welcome message to the OP states that this is not a discussion forum but that it what all the commenting becomes.

Comment: @RichardRasch I see no problem with this being an answer (considering it is posted as a potential solution to the question).  If possible, though, could you please [edit] your answer to include some explanation why this could work